# regex character span

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to understand more about regular expressions (working though some tutorials) in R and have come across something I can't get to work.  I'm trying to grab spans of things between 2 characters (including those characters and replace them).  Could someone help me to get the desired behavior out of these regexes?

```
d <- c("xtfo_oin5h;lx", "6b_arin;7", "xin;7")
gsub("t.+?l", "HERE", b)
gsub("_.+?\\;", "HERE", b)

Desired outcomes for these two statements:
[1] "xHEREx"    "6b_arin;7" "xin;7"
[1] "xtfoHERElx" "6bHERE7"     "xin;7"
```

Comment: Maybe because you're `gsub`bing vector `b` while your actual vector is `d`?

Comment: Also, I think the desired outcome for the first pattern should be: `[1] "xHEREx"    "6b_arin;7" "xin;7"`. There's nothing in your `gsub` to deal with removing semicolons from the second and third items in `d`.

Comment: That's it sorry for the bother.  mrdwab can you post the solution?  I was so caught up with different tutorial attempts I inadvertently copied the wrong string.

Comment: @mrdwab I edited the question to reflect your second comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this is just a minor problem of transposition, in this case, mistaking a `b` for a `d`. ;-)

```
gsub("t.+?l", "HERE", d)
gsub("_.+?\\;", "HERE", d)
```

work as expected!

```
> gsub("t.+?l", "HERE", d)
[1] "xHEREx"    "6b_arin;7" "xin;7"    
> gsub("_.+?\\;", "HERE", d)
[1] "xtfoHERElx" "6bHERE7"    "xin;7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
gsub("(.*)t.+?l(.*)", "\\1HERE\\2", d)

gsub("(.*)_.+?\\;(.*)", "\\1HERE\\2", d)
```

but it is a bit unclear from question